# How to prevent browser to stop blocking pop up when iframe loads through document.getElementById('iframe346').src = 'https://www.bing.com/';

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, popup

When I click on the anchor tag it loads iframe in my simple HTML page but I got a warning that the browser blocked the pop-ups. How I can prevent the browser to stop blocking pop-ups.

Here is my snippet:

Html code:

```
 <iframe id="iframe344" src="" title="YouTube video player"></iframe>
       <a onclick="iframe344()"
         href="http://securedbd.com/path/out.php?sxid=0" target="_blank">
         <img src="writing-animation.gif"
           width="40px">
         </a>
```

Javascript code:

```
 function iframe344() {
     document.getElementById('iframe344').style.display = 'block';
     document.getElementById("popup").style.display = "block";
     document.getElementById('iframe344').src = 'https://www.bing.com/';
     setTimeout(function () {
       window.open("https://www.alexa.com/");
     }, 1000);
  }
```

Please help me community

Comment: You can't. This is a browser feature to stop users being bombarded by annoying popups. If you were able to work around the restriction it would make it entirely pointless. To fix the issue, don't use popups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not recommended to allow popups for security purposes but for your testing you can go to chrome->settings->site settings and search Popups and redirects and allow them from there.

Comment: Please upvote my answer if it worked for you